Mathematical guidance with scaling points on a graph
I need help with the maths side for plotting my points on my graph, For my graphing software.
For example, I define my function here with the points I want to plot [[x, y], [x, y]], etc...
graph.plot([[1.52, 0.4], [1.86, 0.5], [2.32, 0.6]])

In the code for the function, the problem is that I am multiplying my x and y points from the 2d array by 100 to scale. It is not particularly nice, but it does scale to some extent. I am trying to achieve a way that scales any point to the graph and If I need to use different points instead of the ones provided above. It would scale to the size of the graph accordingly. So the points use advantage of the entire graph provided instead of plotting the points in a small scale area.
def plot(self, points):
    for point in points:
       x, y = point

        plot_x = self.axis_x + (x * 100) # testing x
        plot_y = self.axis_y - (y * 100) # testing y

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), (plot_x, plot_y), 5)

The code: graph.plot([[1.52, 0.4], [1.86, 0.5], [2.32, 0.6]]) plots this graph:

When it should plot a graph like this so it is nicely plotted (I added values on x, and y to make it easier to understand) (this is a sketch)

Here is the entire code, If needed: text

What is graph? (where does it come from?). Mostly: what's drawing the grid and axes, because it's unclear what those gridlines represent. It looks like both axes start at 0 with 0.1 minor divisions and 1.0 major divisions, so the plot you're showing is entirely correct: that's where those coordinates have to be plotted if that's the axes you're working with.

Usually you don't modify your point values, you just change the axes bounds. How exactly you do that depends on the plotting library, they usually have some kind of an argument to "autoscale" the axis

The easiest way is to define a rectangle that you want to display on the screen.
To transform coordinates to this rectangle you need 2 transformations: scaling + translation.
For these transformations you need 2 parameters for each coordinate.
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max.
Use them instead of axis_x, axis_y.
Here's what these transformations look like individually.
translation: 
    plot_x = x - x_min
scaling: 
    plot_x = x / (x_max - x_min)

And here's how they look together.
translation + scaling: 
    plot_x = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)

This will display the contents of the given rectangle in the square (0, 0) - (1, 1).
In order to bring this to screen coordinates, you need to perform reversed operations, but with screen constraints.
The final formula is as follows:
plot_x = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min) * screen_width - (screen_width / 2)

The boundaries of the displayed rectangle can be found by knowing the minimum and maximum coordinate among the points.
For your example [[1.52, 0.4], [1.86, 0.5], [2.32, 0.6]]
x_min = 1.52
x_max = 2.32
y_min = 0.4
y_max = 0.6

In this version of the rectangle assignment, it will be disproportionately stretched on the screen, which can sometimes be a good thing.
But if you want to keep the proportions, then the length of one of the sides should be recalculated based on the proportion.
